# jqGrid: Cannot use keyboard to focus and act on icons for edit/delete/page-navigation

Tags: jqgrid

You cannot <TAB> into the icons for edit/delete/page-navigation and <ENTER> to carry out the corresponding actions. These icons do not get focus as you  over different 'actionable' items (e.g. links, input elements). How can this behavior be achieved?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this answers your question or not, but I was having a similar problem.  here is what I ended up doing.  In my link formatters I changed the links to buttons and kepboard navigation and actuation is now available.

In the colModel shown below for 'LastName' I have a link formatter of 'lastNameFormatter'

```
        colModel: [
        { name: 'RequestDate', index: 'RequestDate', search: false, width: 110, fixed: true, editable: false, align: 'left', cellStyle:'padding-left:5px', title: false, formatter: ndateFormatter },
        { name: 'LastName', index: 'LastName', search: false, width: 110, title: false, formatter: lastNameFormatter },
        { name: 'DlNum', index: 'DlNum', search: false, width: 130, align: 'left', title: false },
        { name: 'DlState', index: 'DlState', search: false, width: 50, align: 'left', title: false },
        { name: 'UserName', index: 'UserName', search: false, width: 180, align: 'left', title: false, resizable: true },
        { name: 'AuthCode', index: 'AuthCode', search: false, hidden: false, width: 85, sortable: false, formatter: viewLinkFormatter, align: 'left', title: true},
        { name: 'ProbationDescription', index: 'ProbationDescription', search: false, sortable: false, hidden: true, title: false}
    ],
```

Which then does the following:

```
function lastNameFormatter(cellval, opts, rwdat, _act) {
var probationDescription = rwdat.ProbationStatusDescription;
if ((probationDescription == null) ||
    (probationDescription.toLowerCase() == "accepted")) {
    return "<button type='button' class='jqGridButton' onclick='submitView(\"" + rwdat.AuthCode + "\"); return false;' >" + cellval + "</button>";
} else {
    return cellval;
}
```

So...  using a button here seems to do the trick for allowing keyboard navigation of the jqGrid links.

Maybe not an exact answer but hope you find something of use here.